# What is the best way to deliver my website to a web designer to work on?

Tags: web-applications

I am nearing completion of a web application that I've been building for quite a while now, mainly in PHP.  I  intend to outsource the design of the website (html, css) to a designer on elance.  Being that this is my first time, I have some questions to make sure the process goes smoothly.

1. What is the best way to deliver the site to them to work on?  There are aspects of the site that execute shell commands and require the presence of my mysql db in order to access.  In order for them to design the site, they will need to access these pages.  What is the best way to accomplish this?  Should I place it on my web server and allow them to work on the live site?  If it matters, I am running a local server on Ubuntu and have subversion setup on my Linode server.
2. Are most designers familiar with PHP and able to sort through the code to design the site?
3. Any other tips for someone who has never outsourced the design of a site?  The site has maybe 100 pages, many with very similar structures.  Is it more cost effective to have them deliver the CSS/HTML for each of the structures and then implement across the rest of the site myself?

Thanks so much for your help.  I'm happy to provide any needed specifics.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a lot of this will depend on who you are looking to outsource to. Is it going to be a design company, a single designer, a firm with designers and developers? In most pipelines, the site is designed before it is developed, so this may come as a bit of a backwards process. But this is just from my liminted perspective.

For each of your questions, it will depend on the designer. If you are willing to pay more, you could find someone who is a great designer AND knows HTML/CSS (and even PHP), but if funds are limited, it might be difficult to find someone who is exceptional at both. Paying more, you could likely give them access to what you've done so far and let them have at it.

If you go the less expensive route, it may be easiest to simply sit down with a designer and give them as much information as you can, and then let them work on a mockup in something like Photoshop. You could then periodically iterate on their designs until you are satisfied, implementing everything code-related yourself when finished. This would require more work and time on your part, but would definitely cost much less.

So depending on your approach, there are a few ways to go about it. Hopefully this helps, but let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would actually be best to have them work on the design itself using information you provide (maybe some print screens of different pages, and other specifications) so they can have context and then you apply the HTML/CSS, etc to the pages yourself. This is probably the best approach especially if you do not want strangers to have a "copy" of your website with them...